# CUDA - class member dynamic changing in __device__ function

Tags: c++, oop, cuda

I have tried to use a polynomial class in CUDA.
The class definition is as follow:

```
template<int Degree>
class Polynomial{
    public:
        float coefficients[Degree+1];
};

template<int Degree>
class StartingPolynomial{
    public:
        Polynomial<Degree> p;
        float start;
};

template<int Degree>
class PPolynomial{
    public:
        size_t polyCount;
        StartingPolynomial<Degree>* polys;
};
```

The output of PPolynomial class is something like:

```
[-0.750000,-0.250000]   1.5000 x^0 +4.0000 x^1 +2.6667 x^2 
[-0.250000,0.250000]    1.0000 x^0 +0.0000 x^1 -5.3333 x^2 
[0.250000,0.750000] 1.5000 x^0 -4.0000 x^1 +2.6667 x^2 
[0.750000,Infinity] 0.0000 x^0 +0.0000 x^1 +0.0000 x^2
```

I write a __device__ function try to change the data member in __global__ function. But I failed and got warned that is an illegal access.

```
ERROR: /home/davidxu/CLionProjects/Practice/main.cu:973,code:700,reason:an illegal memory access was encountered
```

I write a test program and I still can't figure out how to change the data member.

Program:

```
#include "cuda.h"
#include "cstdio"
#include "cuda_runtime.h"

template<int Degree>
class Polynomial{
    public:
        float coefficients[Degree+1];
};

template<int Degree>
class StartingPolynomial{
    public:
        Polynomial<Degree> p;
        float start;
};

template<int Degree>
class PPolynomial{
    public:
        size_t polyCount;
        StartingPolynomial<Degree>* polys;
};

template<int Degree>
__device__ void scale(PPolynomial<Degree> *pp,const float& scale){
    for(int i=0;i<pp->polyCount;++i){
        printf("change start\n");
        printf("start is %f\n",pp->polys[i].start);
        atomicExch(&pp->polys[i].start,scale*pp->polys[i].start);
        printf("start ok\n");
        float s2=1.0;
        for(int j=0;j<=Degree;++j){
            printf("change polys\n");
            pp->polys[i].p.coefficients[j]*=s2;
            printf("polys ok\n");
            s2/=scale;
        }
    }
}
__global__ void test(PPolynomial<2> *pp){
    scale(pp,0.5);
}

int main(){
    PPolynomial<2> pp;
    pp.polyCount=2;
    pp.polys=(StartingPolynomial<2>*)malloc(sizeof(StartingPolynomial<2>)*pp.polyCount);
    pp.polys[0].start=-1;
    /* pp.polys.p.coefficients[0]=1; */
    pp.polys[0].start=1;
    /* pp.polys.p.coefficients[0]=2; */

    PPolynomial<2> *pd=NULL;
    cudaMalloc((PPolynomial<2>**)&pd,sizeof(pp));
    cudaMemcpy(pd,&pp,sizeof(pp),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    test<<<1,1>>>(pd);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

output:

```
change start
```

I try to pass the pram to __global__ function by input the address of device variable, but the kernel function seems to be dead at last. That makes me really confused.

How can I solve my problem?

Edit 1:

I find out that the pointer **pd->polys** points to host address(Although **pd** is a pointer to device address).Is there an elegant way to copy the whole PPolynomial object from host to device?

Comment: You copy the```Ppolynomial``` to the GPU but not the ```StartingPolynomials```. Those are still in host memory

Comment: I'm also suddenly aware of this... But I sill wonder how to copy the `StartPolynomials` with `PPolynomial` elegantly. Maybe I can write a host function like `__host__ void set()` to copy the whole object to device? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If you are on Linux, you could make your life easier by using unified memory (`cudaMallocManaged`). You could even use the `thrust::cuda::universal_allocator` from the Thrust library included with the CUDA Toolkit to avoid the C API. This memory is accessible form both host and device (there is automatic page migration happening in the background). This might not give optimal performance depending on how you use it, but if you identify it as a bottleneck later on, you can still get into doing it manually. It is nice for trying out thing without worrying about these details yet.

Comment: For doing it manually: First copy over the `StartingPolynomials`, then create a device version of `PPolynomial` with the new device addresses.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your detailed reply. I already know how to solve my problem.